# How to link users from other Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to link two apps with different databases models. I already routing  but when I want to link the users.user models with myapp.UserView gives me this error:

```
(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'users.User', which is either not
installed, or is abstract.
(fields.E307) The field with myapp.UserView.user was declared with a lazy reference to 
'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Myapp.model.py

```
class UserView(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    view_id = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    view_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

users.model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django User model is independent of your apps. So you'll only need to import it like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserView(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    view_id = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    view_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: I just changed and it works but it created auth_user table in myapp database and created a restriction to this one. I think the auth_users tables should just be in my users app.